# WPF Graphing / Charting control

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

I want to produce an interactive chart - so far I've found [GraphSharp](http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=28088) which looked very promising, however I've found myself struggling due to lack of documentation and a difficult to understand sample.

All I need is to be able to place arbitrary WPF controls as my "nodes", have arrows joining them and be able to collapse / expand parts of the tree (users dont need to be able to move controls or anything like that).

None of the above strikes me as particularly complex (especially not in WPF), and I don't need anything fancy, however I'm aware that getting this bug free and behaving nicely could still end up take me a fair amount of time.

Is there a WPF layout control / library which can help me out with this, or am I better off creating my own?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into the WPF Controlkit by Microsoft - you can find on CodePlex.

Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Telerik controls (not free)? The free Silverlight Toolkit on Codeplex doesn't suit your needs?